# concerning the usage of the measurement scale "meter"

Tags: grammar

Would you answer my question? Thanks in advance.

A:  The meter is easier to use than the yard when the cloth is sold.

B:  The cloth is sold by the meter.

Both examples are of my own making for seeing if the measurement scale "meter" is rightly used.
  I sometimes see a sentence like B and I think it's right.
However, how about A, in which "the meter" is used at the position of a subject, not after the preposition "by"?

One more please.
  Can I say "the meter" generalizes individual meters?

Comment: The metre isn’t used in the US, except in science, where it is spelled the original French way, as in English-speaking countries where it is used.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with either sentence, and also no problem with using *the* when referring to a general concept. But it's not entirely clear what your *specific* question is here.

Comment: Thank you David and Jason Bassford.

Comment: A is OK, but many might say "Meters are easier to use than yards".

Comment: OTOH, I wouldn't say "the cloth is sold", but just "cloth is sold".

Comment: Thank you Barmar. 
  You said, 'I wouldn't say "the cloth is sold", but just "cloth is sold".' 
  －You are right. I just miswrote.